# Why are the stellar winds of some stars composed of neutral particles?

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics, stars

A few years ago I was visiting a colleague to give the physics colloquium at their university and had a chance to chat with some of the professors in the Physics and Astronomy department.  One of the astronomers was working [stellar winds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_wind) from a type of massive star (unfortunately I don't recall if they were [Wolf–Rayet stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf%E2%80%93Rayet_star) or just large stars).

If memory serves me, the argument was that massive stars have stellar winds which are driven by radiation pressure and that pressure transfers momentum with little or no heating.  This made little sense to me then and still does not make sense to me now.

**How can the gas that the photons are "pushing" start neutral if it left from the surface of a massive star?**

That is, presumably the massive star's stellar winds would have evacuated most of the previously present gas in the region after ignition, right?  So any constituents comprising the stellar wind should come from the upper atmosphere of the massive star, correct?  If so, why is it assumed they are neutral?  If the particles are neutral atoms, how did they become neutral (i.e., did recombination occur in the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere) or beyond or below)?

Comment: If the gas is dense enough (or resident near the star long enough), then recombination is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @JonCuster - Yes, well perhaps that's my hangup.  The density of the solar photosphere is huge compared to the solar wind at 1 AU, but even so, the photosphere is ionized.  Are the stellar winds of massive stars more dense and cooler than the solar photosphere?